# How to mock library class for Pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am new in mock and tests for python code(whatever code).

I'm trying to test my function main.py

```
def get_channel_list():
    sc = SlackClient(get_token())
    channels_list_json = sc.api_call("channels.list")
    if channels_list_json['ok'] == True:
        return channels_list_json
```

that is function that I'm trying to test

I need to mock patch `sc.api_call("channels.list")` to return JSON object 
but I can't find any examples like this that would help me to figure out how to do it.

Evrething I found was like this example [Mocking a class method...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406848/mocking-a-class-method-and-changing-some-object-attributes-in-python)

I think it would look like this:

```
@patch.object(SlackClient, 'api_call')
def test_get_channel_list():
    assert get_channel_list() != ""
```

I don't have to to test lib I need to test the rest of my code in the function that I mentioned before.
Thanks for any help, I'm realy stack with this test.

Comment: I think you need to write a mock function to return the json and mention that in the `patch` decorator. If you add you mock function we might be able ot piece together the parts for you.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you mean

Comment: You need something that to "return json object" - which you haven't included in the question. I could make something up - but wondered if there was something more specific than that you hadn't mentioned.

Comment: it doesn't realy matter what to return it could be just python dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a separate mock function to return a JSON object.

You can try this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_api_call(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(SlackClient, 'api_call', lambda self, arg: {"ok": True})

def test(mock_api_call):
    sc = SlackClient(get_token())
    channels_list_json = sc.api_call("channels.list")
    assert True == channels_list_json['ok']

def test_get_channel_list(mock_api_call):
    channels_list_json = get_channels_list()
    assert dict == type(channels_list_json)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for this answer it helped me