# Python mock - mocking class method that modifies class attributes

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

I currently have the following basic Python class that I want to test:

```
class Example:

    def run_steps(self):
        self.steps = 0

        while self.steps < 4:
            self.step()
    
    def step(self):
        # some expensive API call
        print("wasting time...")
        time.sleep(1000)

        self.steps += 1
```

As you can see, the step() method contains an expensive API call so I want to mock it with another function that avoids the expensive API call but still increments `self.steps`. I found that this is possible by doing this (as seen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406848/mocking-a-class-method-and-changing-some-object-attributes-in-python)):

```
def mock_step(self):
    print("skip the wasting time")
    self.steps += 1

# This code works!
def test(mocker):
    example = Example()
    mocker.patch.object(Example, 'step', mock_step)

    example.run_steps()
```

I simply create a function called `mock_step(self)` that avoids the API call, and I patch the original slow `step()` method with the new `mock_step(self)` function.

However, this causes a new problem. Since the `mock_step(self)` function is not a Mock object, I can't call any of the Mock methods on it (such as assert_called() and call_count()):

```
def test(mocker):
    example = Example()
    mocker.patch.object(Example, 'step', mock_step)

    example.run_steps()

    # this line doesn't work
    assert mock_step.call_count == 4
```

To solve this issue, I have tried to wrap `mock_step` with a Mock object using the `wraps` parameter:

```
def test(mocker):
    example = Example()

    # this doesn't work
    step = mocker.Mock(wraps=mock_step)
    mocker.patch.object(Example, 'step', step)

    example.run_steps()

    assert step.call_count == 4
```

but then I get a different error saying `mock_step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

So from this stage I am not sure how I can assert that `step()` has been called exactly 4 times in `run_steps()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions to this, the simplest is probably using a standard mock with a side effect:

```py
def mock_step(self):
    print("skip the wasting time")
    self.steps += 1


def test_step(mocker):
    example = Example()
    mocked = mocker.patch.object(Example, 'step')
    mocked.side_effect = lambda: mock_step(example)
    example.run_steps()
    assert mocked.call_count == 4
```

`side_effect` can take a callable, so you can both use a standard mock and the patched method.

Comment: I tested your solution with an `import mock` instead of injecting `mocker`. But you seem to patch the class' **definition of the method**, not the actual **method bound to the object**, which results in the time-wasting code being called.

Comment: @Lenormju -  well, I tested the code as is and it works for me (e.g. doesn't call the production code). I used the mocker because the question used it and it is more convenient with `pytest`. Also I wanted to allow using the  standard `mock` to allow for `call_count`, `assert_called_xxx` etc. instead of just doing the count myself (which is also a solution, of course).

Comment: you are correct, I missed that it was present in the OP's code, I just had to `pip install pytest-mock` and it worked. Yours is a better solution than mine :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I wasn't aware that `mocker.patch` returned a Mock of the patched object so it never occurred to me to do something like `mocked = mocker.patch.object(Example, 'step')`. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import unittest.mock as mock
from functools import partial


def fake_step(self):
    print("faked")
    self.steps += 1


def test_api():
    api = Example()
    with mock.patch.object(api, attribute="step", new=partial(fake_step, self=api)):
        # we need to use `partial` to emulate that a real method has its `self` parameter bound at instantiation
        api.run_steps()
    assert api.steps == 4
```

Correctly outputs `"faked"` 4 times.